# Casting explicitly-laid out structures

Tags: c#, casting, struct, type-conversion

Let's say I have this structure,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Chapter4Time
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt16 Unused;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public UInt16 TimeHigh;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt16 TimeLow;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public UInt16 MicroSeconds;
}
```

and this structure.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IEEE_1588Time
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt32 NanoSeconds;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt32 Seconds;
}
```

How would I convert from one structure to the other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options here:

**No unsafe code, but explicit structure layout**

(Note that although this isn't unsafe as far as the C# compiler is concerned, some frameworks may still disallow it - see Marc Gravell's comment.)

You could use a union type, which is just another struct with two fields, both set explicitly to the same location. Here's a complete example using your structures:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Chapter4Time
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt16 Unused;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public UInt16 TimeHigh;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt16 TimeLow;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    public UInt16 MicroSeconds;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IEEE_1588Time
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public UInt32 NanoSeconds;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public UInt32 Seconds;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct TimeUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Chapter4Time Chapter4Time;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IEEE_1588Time IEEE_1588Time;
}

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        var ch4 = new Chapter4Time { TimeLow = 100, MicroSeconds = 50 };
        var union = new TimeUnion { Chapter4Time = ch4 };
        Console.WriteLine(union.IEEE_1588Time.Seconds);
    }
}
```

**Unsafe code, casting pointers**

An alternative to the union type if you can use unsafe code is to cast a pointer of type `Chapter4Time*` to `IEEE_1588Time*`:

```
class Test
{    
    unsafe static void Main()
    {
        var ch4 = new Chapter4Time { TimeLow = 100, MicroSeconds = 50 };
        var ieee1588 = *((IEEE_1588Time*) &ch4);
        Console.WriteLine(ieee1588.Seconds);
    }
}
```

Personally I'd avoid doing any of this if at all possible, but if you *really, *really* want to do it, these are probably the simplest approaches.

Comment: Why would one avoid it?  Isn't that the whole point of explicit layout?  In other news, I do have methods that marshal structs to byte arrays, so I could certainly make two method calls and do the same thing, but that seemed like overkill.

Comment: I was sure there was some simple function that could do the same thing. A union type is just compiler trickery. Unsafe code, pin both structs to the same memory address, return the result?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, I was just editing it to show the unsafe version, having remembered it myself. But personally I still don't like doing this - it makes assumptions about endianness, for example. My experience is that this kind of approach often leads to brittle code.

Comment: The specification for these structures is intended for C programs, where such casting is commonplace.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yup, and it's just as brittle there :) I've written code like this before (in C) and found it to be painful... as well as not being portable to other architectures.

Comment: @Jon just a side note - unrelated to the "unsafe" compiler switch etc, but: there are some frameworks that disallow "unsafe" code completely; they typically disallow unions as well. Meaning: some parts of the CLI already treat unions as unsafe code. Which makes a lot of sense really.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yup, that does make a lot of sense. Will edit that in.