# How to implicitly cast this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interop

I'm trying to create some wrapper classes around some native DLL structs. Here's what I've got:

```
public class Event // <-- managed class
{
    internal SDL_Event _event;

    public EventType Type
    {
        get { return (EventType) _event.type; }
    }

    public KeyboardEvent Key
    {
        get
        {
            return new KeyboardEvent(_event.key); // <-- I want to avoid making a copy of the struct here
        }
    }
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal unsafe struct SDL_Event // <-- a union holding ~15 different event types
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public UInt32 type;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public SDL_KeyboardEvent key;

    [FieldOffset(0)] private fixed byte _padding[56];
}

public class KeyboardEvent
{
    private SDL_KeyboardEvent _event;

    internal KeyboardEvent(SDL_KeyboardEvent e)
    {
        _event = e;
    }

    // some properties that deal specifically with SDL_KeyboardEvent 
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SDL_KeyboardEvent
{
    public UInt32 type; // <-- sits in the same memory location as SDL_Event.type
    public UInt32 timestamp;
    public UInt32 windowID;
    public byte state;
    public byte repeat;
    private byte _padding2;
    private byte _padding3;
    public SDL_Keysym keysym;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SDL_Keysym
{
    public UInt32 scancode;
    public Int32 sym;
    public UInt16 mod;
    private UInt32 _unused;
}
```

`Event` is supposed to wrap `SDL_Event` and `KeyboardEvent` should wrap `SDL_KeyboardEvent`. I would essentially like to "cast" `Event` to `KeyboardEvent` when `Event.Key` is accessed, without copying any data around. Ideally, `Event` would be directly castable to `KeyboardEvent` too.

Comment: Since both structs have the same data, why make 2 structs? Let the classes use inheritance, and use the native event property from the parent

Comment: @MEYWD: They *don't* exactly have the same data. The data just shares the same memory space; a few of the member variables might be the same, but they aren't all the same.

Comment: Can you use Explicit Layout, and put `NativeEvent` and  `NativeKeyboardEvent` in a union struct? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17641729

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes. It's a little messy, but that's what I'm doing now.

Comment: Why not use the unsafe way in that link?

Comment: @MEYWD: For one, I'm getting this error "You can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer". I'm going to update the question with some more concrete code.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsafe static SDL_KeyboardEvent ToSDL_KeyboardEvent (SDL_Event event)
{
    return *((SDL_KeyboardEvent*) &event);
}
```

That's the best I can do with the structs.  For the classes, you'll have to write some explicit casts in the usual way, but this should help with those.

Comment: Regarding the explicit casts, C# won't let you explicitly cast from a base class to a derived class.

Comment: Further, this method accomplishes the cast, but still copies the entire 56-byte structure into an out of this method if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: They're structs.  What did you expect?  If you want that kind of finesse, you need to copy the members directly.  I didn't see any inheritance going on in your original code.

Comment: Yes.. they're structs because that's how they're defined in C. That's why I'm wrapping them in classes, so that users of my API don't have to deal with that crap. I'm trying not to introduce any extra overhead.

Comment: Then you might have better luck writing bonafide classes that accept the original struct in the constructor for hydration.  You can even overload the constructors if you like, so that they can accept either struct.